# qmlcachegen via CMake: could not find a Qt installation of ''

Tags: cmake, qt5, qmake

I have a Linux based operating system that, by default, does **not** provide a `default.conf` for `qtchooser` which results in:

```
$ qmake
qmake: could not find a Qt installation of ''

$ qmlcachegen
qmlcachegen: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

Generally you would solve this by manually specifying a version:

```
$ qmake -qt5 -v
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.11.3 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

$ QT_SELECT=5 qmake -v
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.11.3 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

It can also be solved by creating files such as:

- `/etc/xdg/qtchooser/default.conf`
- `/usr/share/qtchooser/default.conf`
- etc.

However, for the sake of this question my OS does not provide this file.

#### Problem

When using CMake 3.13.4 this works fine (optionally by providing `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/path/to/qt`):

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core)

qt5_add_resources(RESOURCES assets.qrc)

target_link_libraries(my_app PUBLIC
        Qt5::Core)
```

However, when trying to use QML [ahead-of-time compilation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-deployment.html#ahead-of-time-compilation) we are instructed to replace `qt5_add_resources()` with `qtquick_compiler_add_resources()`

```
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core QuickCompiler)

qtquick_compiler_add_resources(RESOURCES assets.qrc)

[...]
```

Which will use `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5QuickCompiler/Qt5QuickCompilerConfig.cmake` to find the location of the binary `qmlcachegen` and use that to compile QML files.

So CMake ends up doing something like `execve("/usr/bin/qmlcachegen", resource_files);`.

But `/usr/bin/qmlcachegen` does not know about any Qt installation, so it fails:

```
[ 15%] Generating qml_components_ChatScrollToBottomButton_qml.cpp
make[3]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/conversations_autogen.dir/build.make:85: src/qml_components_Chat_qml.cpp] Error 1
qmlcachegen: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

### Question

Even though we've used CMake to determine what Qt installation to use, `qmlcachegen` has its own logic for finding the path to Qt. Judging from `Qt5QuickCompilerConfig.cmake` there is no way to provide either an environment variable `QT_SELECT` or pass the `-qt5` argument.

1. Is it the responsibility of my OS to provide a `default.conf` so that Qt can find the installation?
2. Is it the responsibility of CMake to correctly pass the necessary context before calling `qmlcachegen`?

Answer (score 0):

`qt5-default` adds `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser//default.conf` and thus `qmake` and `qmlcachegen` will be able to find the default Qt install.